# Controlling the windows mouse from a service

Tags: windows, winapi, service, remote-access, vnc

I am writing a remote control client which needs to control the Windows 10 mouse pointer. I am using Win32 to setmousepointer, but when I want to run as a service there is no desktop session associated with the service.
I need to run as a service, because I want to control the mouse right after startup (from the login screen).

I know that VNC, Logmein, and Teamviewer can do this (control the mouse from the login screen). What is their approach?

Comment: Launch a client application in the respective interactive session(s) from your service, and have that client application perform the operations, that inherently rely on an interactive session.

Comment: @IInspectable  How do I do that if no user has logged on yet? Does the "interactive session" already exist before the user logs on? I want this service to be active as soon as the machine powers up, so that it can control the login screen.